# When javascript is disabled, React event does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am referring to the following example for Node and React: https://github.com/yldio/react-example

I am able to add a book to the array when javascript is enabled in Chrome. When I disable javascript in Chrome, I am not able to add a book to the array.

Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: What do you think disabling javascript in the browser does?

Comment: @Jason what i m trying to do is even if javascript is disabled if content is displayed using node then add should also work. I m trying to understand why does it not work

Comment: Node is server side, it does not run in your browser.  Same thing as if you're talking in the phone after the other side hung up.  Just because you're talking doesn't mean the other side is going to hear you because the receiving end is disabled.

Answer (score 22):

> Is there any way to resolve this?

Not in the way that you're hoping.

React is a JavaScript framework for the front-end. Which means it executes in the browser. If you disable JavaScript in the browser, React doesn't work anymore. Just in the same way if you delete Photoshop from your computer, you can't open .psd files anymore.

If you really must support browsers without JavaScript (which most people don't), you need to build your app to work with plain old HTML based navigation (think links, forms etc).

It's possible to use React (for people with JS enabled) and a fallback for those without, this approach is called **Progressive Enhancement**. Might be useful to you: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25969/should-i-bother-to-develop-for-javascript-disabled

Comment: Targeting JS users first with a fallback is graceful degradation.